# How to complete Vuetify's circular progress bar on middle percentage value?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, progress-bar

I am using Vuetify's [progress circular component](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/progress-circular/) that takes a `value` prop which is the percentage of current progress and the circle gets completed when the percentage value reaches 100.
My use case is to create a countdown and I can have a max percentage value of let's say 10, which means the circle should show completed on a value of 10. But I can't figure out a way to complete the circle on the middle percentage value.

Is this possible anyhow?

Here is my example code where I want my 10-value and 20-value circles to be filled like the 100-value circle.

**Note-** The value could be any multiple of 10, like 10, 20, 30, 50, etc.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      second_10: 10,
      second_20: 20,
      second_100: 100,
      interval_10: null,
      interval_20: null,
      interval_100: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    countDown(val) {
      this[`interval_${val}`] = setInterval(() => {
         if(this[`second_${val}`] == 0) {
           this[`second_${val}`] = val
         } else {
           this[`second_${val}`]--;
         }
      }, 1000)
    },
    stopCountDown() {
      clearInterval(this.interval_10);
      clearInterval(this.interval_20);
      clearInterval(this.interval_100)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.1/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.1/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12" align="center">
          <v-btn small color="error" @click="stopCountDown()">Stop Timer</v-btn>
        </v-col>
        <v-col>
          <v-btn small @click="countDown(100)">start timer</v-btn>
          <v-progress-circular
            :rotate="360"
            :size="50"
            :width="5"
            :value="second_100"
            color="success"
            class="mt-3"
            >
            {{ second_100 }}
          </v-progress-circular>
        </v-col>
        <v-col>
          <v-btn small @click="countDown(10)">start timer</v-btn>
          <v-progress-circular
            :rotate="360"
            :size="50"
            :width="5"
            :value="second_10"
            color="success"
            class="mt-3"
            >
            {{ second_10 }}
          </v-progress-circular>
        </v-col>
        <v-col>
          <v-btn small @click="countDown(20)">start timer</v-btn>
          <v-progress-circular
            :rotate="360"
            :size="50"
            :width="5"
            :value="second_20"
            color="success"
            class="mt-3"
            >
            {{ second_20 }}
          </v-progress-circular>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the multiplier to reach 100 from your initial countdown value. Just do `counter * (100 / initialCounterValue)` to get it.

This only concern here is that the initial counter value must be a multiple of 100. It won't work well with like `18` haha

I'd suggest to make a component so that this logic is in a single place:

```html
<template>
  <v-col>
     <v-btn small @click="startCountdown">start timer</v-btn>
     <v-progress-circular
        :rotate="360"
        :size="50"
        :width="5"
        :value="counter * (100 / from)"
        color="success"
        class="ms-4"
     >
       {{ counter }}
     </v-progress-circular>
   </v-col>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    from: { type: Number, default: 10 }
  },
  data() {
    return {
       counter: this.from,
       interval: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    startCountdown() {
       this.interval = setInterval(() => {
          if (this.counter <= 0 && this.interval) {
             clearInterval(this.interval)
          } else {
             this.counter--;
          }
       }, 1000)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Example with the formula:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      second_100: 100,
      second_20: 20,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    countDown(val) {
      setInterval(() => {
         if(this[`second_${val}`] == 0) {
           this[`second_${val}`] = val
         } else {
           this[`second_${val}`]--;
         }
      }, 1000)
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.1/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.1/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-row>
        <v-col>
          <v-btn small @click="countDown(100)">start timer</v-btn>
          <v-progress-circular
            :rotate="360"
            :size="50"
            :width="5"
            :value="second_100"
            color="success"
            class="ms-4"
            >
            {{ second_100 }}
          </v-progress-circular>
        </v-col>
        <v-col>
          <v-btn small @click="countDown(20)">start timer</v-btn>
          <v-progress-circular
            :rotate="360"
            :size="50"
            :width="5"
            :value="second_20 * (100/20)"
            color="success"
            class="ms-4"
            >
            {{ second_20 }}
          </v-progress-circular>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Kapcash. This would indeed work for value 10 but not for 20, 30, etc. I edited my question, sorry for not adding the information earlier.

Comment: Got it! I updated my answer with a generic component that can handle all counters value, as long as they are a multiple of 100.